# Convert Date to Time

Tags: java, mysql, date, time, phpmyadmin

I'm having some issues with a pre-made Java master table.

The problem is that it requires to show an inserted date from my PHPMyAdmin in the form off dd-mm-yyyy-hh-mm-ss, but instead it only shows dd-mm-yyyy. Only if I edit it in the application itself it shows me the correct form.

I know some methods to format it but I could not figure out how to use these in a premade master table.

Comment: your question is not clear? what have you tried, where is code?

Comment: not sure what precisely you need, but in general java.util.Date ( http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Date.html ) or some of its subclasses should help

Answer (score 0):

Use DateAndTime in Java and in your PhpMyAdmin have you declare a Date and Time or just Date?